# System.Net.WebException when trying to consume WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing system composed of WCF service and Xamarin.Forms client app. Seems like my application connects to server just fine (client has status Open when I check before invoking any methods), but after I try to invoke a service method, I am getting System.Net.WebException:

```
There was no endpoint listening at {0} that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

And the inner exception is:

```
System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web request: Status code 404(NotFound): Not Found
```

I can access service via web browsers on both pc and phone with address http://localhost:4408/DatabaseService.svc or http://192.168.8.106:4408/DatabaseService.svc but I get the exception when I am trying to invoke any methods from my app.

My client app is connecting to the host and invokes methods like this:

```
        public App()
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            dbClient = new DatabaseServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.8.106:4408/DatabaseService.svc"));

            dbClient.Test();
        }
```

My service is hosted by this simple program:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.8.106:4408/DatabaseService.svc");
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DatabaseService.DatabaseService), baseAddress);

            try
            {
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(DatabaseService.IDatabaseService), new WSHttpBinding(), "DatabaseService");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
                {
                    HttpGetEnabled = true
                };
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                selfHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Host Status: " + selfHost.State);
                Console.WriteLine("Host Addresses: " + selfHost.BaseAddresses.Count);
                foreach (var x in selfHost.BaseAddresses)
                    Console.WriteLine("  - " + x.AbsoluteUri);
                Console.WriteLine("<q to close >");
                string command = "";
                while (command != "q")
                    command = Console.ReadLine();


                selfHost.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Host shutdown");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown:\n" + e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Part of my applicationhost.config edited by me is:

```
            <site name="OutdoorGame" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\Studia\Magisterka\Github\Serwer\OutdoorGame\OutdoorGame" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:4408:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:4408:127.0.0.1" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:4408:192.168.8.106" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

I tried to stick to the tips included here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf and I should also mention, that my services are working just fine, when accesed via ISS Express WCF Test Client.

I think I am missing something very simple but I have no clue what would it be. Any help will be much appreciated.

### EDIT1

I probably should also show part of Web.config of the server:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>      
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="DatabaseService.DatabaseService">
        <endpoint
           address="http://192.168.8.106:4409/DatabaseService.svc" 
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
           contract="DatabaseService.IDatabaseService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: You do `new WSHttpBinding(),` on the servicehost and that is not the same as a BasicHttpBinding that you use on the client.

Comment: Do I have to do something more except changing WSHttpBinding to BasicHttpBinding?

Comment: I don't know, it was the obvious and easiest thing to check for me. If we're lucky it fixes your problem. if not, we have a bad day ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so since I don't have much time, I basically gave up on this and just went to previous version of my project. Now my files look like this:

Connecting like this:

```
{
            dbClient = new DatabaseServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.8.106:13409/DatabaseService.svc"));
}
```

applicationhost.config

```
            <site name="DatabaseService" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\Studia\Magisterka\Github\Serwer\OutdoorGame\DatabaseService" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:13409:localhost" />
                  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:13409:192.168.8.106" />
                  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:13409:127.0.0.1" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

My web.config is basically default.

Ports used are different because meanwhile I tried to create a new service (thought that could solve the problem) and that could be the thing.
Thanks to Ding Peng now I know, that I don't need service host, IIS Express is enough to host it.

Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured the endpoint information in the configuration file, you do not need to use the hosting program to configure the endpoint information. Moreover, if the project created using the WCF service application template does not require a program to host it, it can be directly deployed to IIS.

[image]

This project can be deployed directly to IIS or run directly in VS.

Secondly, I suggest you use Add Service Reference to generate the client:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally, you can directly call the service through the automatically generated proxy class.